# How can i sweep out a whole wallet to another address?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, dust, windows, sweep-transaction

Since currently it's not possible to manage multiple addresses easily with one simplewallet instance, I would like to fire them up on the go.

I am on windows with the binaries bitmonerod and simplewallet running.

But the problem is I would like to move every bit out of there. I found `sweep_dust`, but it only sends it back to your own wallet. I don't really know how that could help.

So for example, at the moment, I have a wallet with 0.003315200000 as balance. How would I get the amount out of there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sweep_all` sends all outputs to the address you specify.

However, 0.003315200000 is smaller than the smallest fee, so it is not actually spendable by itself, you'd need other outputs to increase the total so that minimum fee can be paid.

Comment: Its not listed on the doc page yet:
https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc

Since my simplewallet (0.9.4) don't know the command i think i need to wait for a new version than right?

Comment: If you need prebuilt binaries, you'll have to wait, yes.